# Rails Model Test - Fixture Not Valid Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "campaigns". Schema looks like this;

```
t.string "title", null: false
t.string "link", null: false
t.integer "order", null: false
t.bigint "customer_id", null: false
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.bigint "user_id", null: false
t.bigint "project_id", null: false
t.datetime "starts_at"
t.datetime "ends_at"
```

Also I use ActiveRecord field for image.

And my fixture looks like this;

```
campaign_one:
  title: MyString
  link: https://MyString.com
  order: 1
  starts_at: "2010-02-11 11:02:57"
  ends_at: "2010-02-11 11:02:57"
  customer: customer_one
  project: project_one
  user: user_one
```

I write this model test;

```
test 'model test' do
    assert @campaign.valid?
end
```

My test does not pass and gives error. What is wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: add output error ?

Comment: CampainTest #model test [/******test.rb:9]:
Expected false to be truthy.